# Write permission in JNLP not granted

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

We develop quite important app and we need JNLP. My JAR is signed with trusted CA certificate (verified status when running with `jarsigner`). I have `Permissions: all-permissions` in `MANIFEST.MF`. My JNLP looks like this:

```
<jnlp codebase="http://TEST:18080" spec="1.0+" href="/TEST-boot/Test.jnlp">
    <information>
        <vendor>TEST</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://wf-nb:18080/" />
        <description>Testing Testing</description>
    </information>
    <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" />
        <jar href="/TEST/jar/TEST-boot-signed.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="test.package" />
</jnlp>
```

and I STILL get Access denied. The JNLP application should have full-access to the disk and everything, right? If I want to read the system property:

```
21.10.2015 12:14:34.400 [WARN] access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.home" "read")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.home" "read")
```

when calling:

```
public String getSystemProperty(final String key, final String def) {
    return (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() {
            return System.getProperty(key, def);
        }
    });
}
```

This code is taken from applet, where it works good. Should I delete doPrivileged stuff, or it is still needed when running from java web start?

**The secord question:** I am getting connection prompts when I want to use `HttpUrlConnection` in my application (even if it is the same server, from which JNLP app was loaded). Will Java always display this prompt?

Comment: *"My JAR is signed.."*  Using a certificate issued by a CA?  *"The secord problem:"*  Should be taken to a 2nd thread, or a help desk.  SO is a Q&A site.

Comment: Yes, certificate issued by trusted authority. "Second problem" : I meant I am getting prompt something like "This application wants to connect with `http://TEST:18080/`. Do you allow this action?" (it is not exact, I have it in german). Normally, application loaded with JNLP should behave like this?

Comment: You can try to use [Ice Boar](https://github.com/Roche/IceBoar). It run your application outside web start sandbox and you can avoid problems like this easy.